# Add a class to a span with a particular text

Tags: javascript, css, menu

My initial problem is that I want to put custom colours on my main menu titles.
I have done this by using the title + attribute in the CSS.
However I don't want the title attribute to appear when hovered over.
So I had another idea and wondered if it was possible to add a class (with JS) to a specific text? And if so how to do it?

Each menu title has the following structure:
`<span class="menu-text">Random text</span>`

They all have the "menu-text" class and that's why I'm trying to differentiate them. In order to apply a different colour.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score -1):

This illustrates a simple way to add a class to an element when it is clicked.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    // gets the elements with the classname .menu-text in a nodeList
    const getAllElements = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-text');
    
    for (let item of getAllElements) {
      // iterates over all of them, and attaches an event
      item.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // adds the class .has-background-red
        this.classList.add('has-background-red');
      });
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
  /* just for visual purposes */
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
}

.has-background-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="menu-text">Random text</span>
  <span class="menu-text">Random text</span>
  <span class="menu-text">Random text</span>
  <span class="menu-text">Random text</span>
  <span class="menu-text">Random text</span>
  <span class="menu-text">Random text</span>
  <span class="menu-text">Random text</span>
  <span class="menu-text">Random text</span>
  <span class="menu-text">Random text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Clicking is not the issue. The **text content** is the criteria for adding a class. I suggest you re-read the question.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the criteria is the "random text".